# How do I use "gets" on a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I get an error whenever I try to use the function gets within a rake task. Is there a way to make it work?

The error says, "no such file or directory - (rake task name)"

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory...

Comment: It might seem so, but it's not.  See my answer below.  There is quite a bit of confusion about the difference between Kernel#gets and STDIN.gets.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The problem is that [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) (which is what you're calling if you just use `gets` by itself) assumes you're pulling from a file named by the arguments passed to Rake.  That means `gets` tries to return the content of a file called [rake-task-here], which almost certainly doesn't exist.

Try [`STDIN.gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-gets).

Comment: Small nit picking: `$stdin` is probably preferable over `STDIN` here, also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279689/968531

Answer (score -4):

I don't think that you should be using gets in a rake task, if you need to get input from the command line you probably should pass it in as a parameter, but if you post some code that is not working then I am sure you will get a better answer.

Comment: In general, command line arguments _are_ a better option, but there are plenty of good reasons to use gets within a rake task.  Most of them have to do with authentication or verification that you really want to be doing what you tell rake to do. ("deploy production code")