# What is the difference between STDIN and $stdin in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stdin

Ruby has two ways of referring to the standard input: The `STDIN` constant , and the `$stdin` global variable.

Aside from the fact that I can assign a different `IO` object to `$stdin` because it's not a constant (e.g. before forking to redirect IO in my children), what's the difference between `STDIN` and `$stdin`? When should I use each in my code?

If I reassign `$stdin`, does it affect `STDIN`?

And does this also apply to `STDOUT`/`$stdout` and `STDER`/`$stderr`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If `$stdin` is reassigned, `STDIN` is not affected. Likewise `$stdin` is not affected when `STDIN` is reassigned (which is perfectly possible (though pointless), but will produce a warning). However if neither variable has been reassigned, they both point to the same IO object, so calling `reopen`¹ on one will affect the other.

All the built-in ruby methods use `$<` (a.k.a. `ARGF`) to read input. If `ARGV` is empty, `ARGF` reads from `$stdin`, so if you reassign `$stdin`, that will affect all built-in methods. If you reassign `STDIN` it will have no effect unless some 3rd party method uses `STDIN`.

In your own code you should use `$stdin` to be consistent with the built-in methods².

¹ `reopen` is a method which can redirect an IO object to another stream or file. However you can't use it to redirect an IO to a StringIO, so it does not eliminate all uses cases of reassigning `$stdin`.

² You may of course also use `$<`/`ARGF` to be even more consistent with the built-in methods, but most of the time you *don't* want the `ARGF` behavior if you're explicitly using the stdin stream.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the built-in methods use `$<` (the default input stream) and `$>` (the default output stream) and neither `$stdin`/`STDIN` nor `$stdout`/`STDOUT`. In fact, that's pretty much the whole point of `$<` and `$>`: that you can redirect the input and output of methods such as `Kernel#puts` *without* affecting stdin/stdout.

Comment: @Jörg: You're right, that they use `$<` and `$>`, I'll correct that. But you're not right about your second point: `$>` and `$stdout` are aliases, so reassigning one will affect the other (unlike STDOUT which stays unaffected). `$<` is the same as `ARGF`, both of which *cannot* be reassigned. However reassigning `$stdin` *will* affect `$<` and `ARGF` because `ARGF` reads from `$stdin` if `ARGV` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

STDERR and $stderr are pointing to the same thing initially; you can reassign the global variable but you shouldn't mess with the constant. $stdin and STDIN, $stdout and STDOUT pairs are likewise.

I had to change STDERR a couple of times as an alternative to monkey-patching some gems outputting error messages with STDERR.puts. If you reassign with STDERR = $stdout you get a warning while STDERR.reopen('nul', 'w') goes without saying.