# Can I stub STDERR in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I have a simple function that I'd like to test (perhaps mostly to appease simplecov).  The function is:

```
module Utils
  extend self

  def blather(msg)
    msg = "=== " + msg
    STDERR.puts(msg)
    Rails.logger.debug(msg)
  end

end
```

The [RSpec documentation for stubbing](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class) says that:

> Messages can be stubbed on any class, including those in Ruby's core library.

But the following:

```
# file: spec/lib/utils_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe Utils do
  context "blather" do
    it "should print to STDERR" do
      STDERR.any_instance.should_receive(:puts).with("=== zoo")    
      Utils.blather("zoo")
    end
  end
end
```

... I get an error

```
undefined method `any_instance' for #<IO:<STDERR>>
```

Putting aside questions as to whether this test makes any sense, is it possible to stub STDERR (the IO class)?  Is this failing because it's a class method?  Or is there a more sensible strategy for this kind of test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you should typically use `$stderr` rather than `STDERR`.

```
module Utils
  extend self

  def blather(msg)
    msg = "=== " + msg
    $stderr.puts(msg)
    Rails.logger.debug(msg)
  end

end
```

To answer your question, you can do the following in RSpec:

```
describe Utils do
  context "blather" do
    it "should print to stderr" do
      $stderr.should_receive(:puts).with("=== zoo")
      Utils.blather("zoo")
    end
  end
end
```

You just stub the method via `$stderr.should_receive`. Because `$stderr` is a normal object, you can stub methods on it like normal as well as set up expectations on it.

Comment: Yep - see my "Duh" answer below.

Comment: P.S.: Thanks for the tip about preferring $stderr over STDERR -- (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279604/what-is-the-difference-between-stdin-and-stdin-in-ruby explains that $stderr can be reassigned while STDERR cannot).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to write to stderr, so it's usually better to test the resulting string instead of requiring `puts` was called once with specific arguments.

As long as your function uses `$stderr` (which is intended to changable) rather than `STDERR` const, you can use rspec's beautiful [`output` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher):

```
expect { blather("zoo") }.to output(/=== zoo/).to_stderr
```

If you need more control, you could replace `$stderr` (and maybe `stub_const "STDERR"`) with a `StringIO` instance, and make assertions about its `.string` later...
(This is what output matcher [does internally](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/v3.6.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/output.rb#L157-L168).)

Answer (score 1):

Duh.  STDIO is not a class -- it is an instance of IO, so changing:

```
STDERR.any_instance.should_receive(:puts).with("=== zoo")
```

to

```
STDERR.should_receive(:puts).with("=== zoo")
```

makes the test pass.