# How to use Ruby predefined variable $<

Tags: ruby, variables

According to [this site](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html), `$<` is under Predefined variables and it says # See ARGF.

I have seen a code like `$<.map{|x|n,m=x.split.map(&:to_i);...` and using it with command line input.

I googled it but I am not able to find an explanation or how to use it.

How does it differ from `$_`?

Comment: This should help
Its standard input
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279604/what-is-the-difference-between-stdin-and-stdin-in-ruby

All the built-in ruby methods use $< (a.k.a. ARGF) to read input. If ARGV is empty, ARGF reads from $stdin, so if you reassign $stdin, that will affect all built-in methods. If you reassign STDIN it will have no effect unless some 3rd party method uses STDIN.

Comment: Apidock explains ARGF quite well: http://apidock.com/ruby/ARGF

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `ARGF` on that page you'll see;

```
ARGF              # A meta-IO across all files in ARGV. (eg ARGF.each_line...)
```

So you should try `$<.each_line`