# How would I force Kernel#gets to use STDIN#gets in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

So I'm trying to DRY up a Rake task which runs a script that takes user input, and [I've run into the same problem as this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576799/how-do-i-use-gets-on-a-rake-task) - by default, just calling `gets` assumes that the rake argument (in this case, `db:seed`) is a file from which it should read, which of course doesn't exist. I got around this by just calling `STDIN.gets`, which works fine, but I'd love to be able to just use `gets` the way I can use `puts` (Rake seems to have no issue with `STDOUT` by default) - as a static method.

Is there any way to force `Kernel#gets` to read from `STDIN` within Rake? (Or more generally, is there any way to force `Kernel#gets` to read from `STDIN` when it is ostensibly passed a command line argument?) Or would that be a bad practice?

Comment: This is actually general Ruby behavior, not specific to rake; i.e. any script with bare `gets` will try to read from a file named by a command-line option.

Comment: There are ways, but why? `STDIN.gets` is a perfectly elegant solution and how it should be done. The other ways involve code adjusting `$stdin` which might break something else immediately, or paint you into a corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered by @the-tin-man in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178905/how-would-i-force-kernelgets-to-use-stdingets-in-a-rake-task#comment24876627_17178905))

There's really very little advantage to be gained in DRYness from forcing `Kernel#gets` to read from `STDIN` in any context, including Rake. Although it can be done (by modifying `$stdin`), it shouldn't be done because it would just be brittle and hacky.